# Giving bad request with Passport JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I having a problem with the passport req.login, when the user logs in with it´s email and password and passport executes it routes to bad request instead of displaying /productos2, I am using ejs and mongoose

I already tried to request the password and the username directly on the req.login, and still doesn´t work

```
app.get("/productos2", function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
          next();
    res.render("productos2");
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
});


app.post("/login", function(req, res, next) {

    const user = new Credential ({
    username: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
    });


    req.login(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        res.redirect("/productos2");
      });
     }
   });
 });
```

So hat I´m trying to do is to be route it succesfully to productos2 route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
  passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
    res.redirect("/productos2");
  });
```

to

```
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect : '/productos2',
    failureRedirect : '/login',
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
  });
```

Comment: i given this solution by refering this https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/u0qJBc